# Running a JUnit test from Groovy Console

Tags: java, groovy, junit, groovy-console

How can I use the [Groovy Console](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Console) to kick off junit tests?

(Currently using Groovy 1.6.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I currently use:

```
junit.textui.TestRunner.run(MyTest)
```

(Where my junit test class is `MyTest`)

I've tried running:

```
MyTest
```

within the Groovy Console, but that just returns the class instance. Is there an easier way?

Comment: I've done it this way too; combined with log4j config to dump out a junit run

Comment: @saua - I was hoping to be able to just highlight the classname and run that